# Как настроить transition только от active к hover?

Tags: css, css3

Есть пара стилей:

```
tr:hover {
    background-color: var(--hover-color);
    transition: .2s ease;
}

tr:active {
    background-color: var(--link-color);
    transition: .05s ease;
}
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы после нажатия на строку `--link-color` оставался еще полсекунды посредством `transition-delay: .5s`. При этом нельзя допустить задержки при обычном наведении - только от `:active` к `:hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, нужно ловить `:focus`. Чтобы анимация проигралась только 1 раз после нажатия, сделаем ее через `@keyframes`:

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #000;
  --hover-color: #999;
  --active-color: #ccc;
}

button {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 0;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  
}
button:focus {
  animation: focus  1s  ease; 
  /*сделал задержку дольше, для очевидности*/
}

button:hover {
  background-color: var(--hover-color);
}

button:active {
  background-color: var(--active-color);
  animation:none;/*сбрасываем анимацию при нажатии*/
}

@keyframes focus {
from {
  background-color: var(--active-color);
}
50%{
  background-color: var(--active-color);
}
to {
  background-color: var(--hover-color);
}
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

При помощи `:hover:active`.

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #000;
  --hover-color: #999;
  --active-color: #ccc;
}

button {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 0;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: var(--hover-color);
}

button:hover:active {
  background-color: var(--active-color);
  transition-delay: .2s;
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: но ведь это дает задержку перед анимацией нажатия, а не после нее